# Why "had hoped" in this context, is it a mistake?

Tags: past-tense

> I feel so sorry for him, it would be the most terrible feeling in the world not knowing if he killed the woman he loved. I've been to that place before, waking up after a drug binge not knowing what I'd done. I thought I was safe because I was with my fiance, it wasn't until days later that i found out he'd literally pimped me out to at least five other men. I **had hoped** at that point he had been in that kind of trance and not known what he was doing but he admitted needing to get "us" more meth.

I don't understand the use of "had hoped" as the hope began after the discovering of being pimped and finished when he admitted that her fiance  perfectly knew what he was doing.

Comment: The whole extract doesn't look very well written to me. A lot of the tense choices are at least syntactically / semantically "suspect", and not particularly idiomatic. There's no obvious reason for using the highlighted Perfect form ***had hoped***, and immediately following ***had been*** - neither of them meaningfully reflect anything relevant in terms of distinguishing "current narrative reference time" from *earlier* events. Don't sweat the details of such clumsy phrasing, and *certainly* don't copy it!

Comment: It's a bit tasteless to be nitpicking the grammar of a victim of sexual abuse. I assume the past perfect is used to emphasise how far past she is from what she hoped at the time; this is pretty common in informal writing, just as not using the past perfect when grammar books say is also pretty common in informal writing. Most English speakers have never read a grammar book about the correct use of the past perfect.

Comment: @StuartF: We don't have a source, but I'd say this is almost certainly low quality *fiction*. I'm not "nitpicking the grammar of a victim of sexual abuse." But even if I was, it makes no sense to encourage learners to work with this kind of text.

Comment: yes it is a low quality fiction

Answer (score 1):

It is past perfect and correctly formed.

The meaning is in the context of a past-tense narrative.  We understand that the sequence of events is  1. Think I am safe. 2. drug trance/abuse.  3. discover abuse, but hope it was due to fiancé's drug trance, 4. He admits to needing to get "us" more meth.  As the narrative proceeds, the past perfect is used to indicate that the "hope" was before "he admitted".

As is often the case, the past perfect is not absolutely required here, but it is a sensible choice of tense/aspect.